# Typo3 frontend plugin, use _POST data in the controller

Tags: plugins, http-post, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, extension-builder3

I wrote a very simple extension in typo3 v7.6.11 with the extension builder where a visitor can ask for a taxi-ride.

everything works, only that I need to make the request more appealing by asking the pick-up point and the drop-off point ... that request goes to the actual form like this in the template (`requestPid` is the id of the page with the form):

```
<f:form pageUid="{settings.additional.requestPid}" action="form" name="request" object="{Request}">
  <f:render partial="Ticket/RequestNewFields" />
  <f:form.submit value="{f:translate(key: 'tx_wmnltickets_domain_model_ticket.admin.continue')}" />
</f:form>
```

but the formAction in the controler doesn't actually ask anything from the model (`getArguments()` I tried);

```
/**
 * action form
 * 
 * @return void
 */
public function formAction() {
    $this->request->getArguments();
}
```

the request does send the `$_POST` but I see no way to get it into the form ...
if you'd like to see more code to understand, just ask, I don't know what you'd be looking for ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form action should has the request parameter from you form:

```
/**
 * action form
 * 
 * @param array $request
 *
 * @return void
 */
 public function formAction($request) {
 }
```

Then you can access the data with `$request['origin']`

I'm not sure if the variable `$request` is allowed as argument. Maybe you must rename it in the function and in your fluid template if it doesn't work.

Comment: This is the preferred and recommended way to transfer arguments to any action. It causes the parameter to be correctly isolated in a sub-scope of URL arguments in GET as well as POST. One should in nearly all cases stay away from accessing `$this->request->getArguments()` in the controller (there's a much longer explanation why but essentially: the arguments there are not validated or converted). So in *every* single case where you need your controllers to pass/receive arguments: declare the arguments correctly on the controller and use those names when passing the arguments.

Comment: `request` is not a reserved argument name but for reasons of clarity it should be avoided as name of a DTO (data transfer object).

Comment: I used newTicket as variable, just to be sure ... but how do I access `$newTicket['origin']` in my fluid template ?? the only way the variable seems accessible is with `$this->view->assign('ticket', $newTicket);` in function formAction ... but no values ...

Comment: Thats correct, assign the variable to the view (fluid) than you can access origin in fluid by using ```{ticket.origin}```

Comment: there must be some kind of typo somewhere ... it all seems proper but with debug the `ticket` remains `NULL` ... very frustrating

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after renaming the variable?

Comment: By the way: If an answer helped you, please mark the answer as helped.

Comment: the cache did not help ... what about in the f:form I use property instead of name ... could that complicate ? (by the way, of course your answers help, I just did not resolve yet)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123226/discussion-between-rene-pflamm-and-webman).

Comment: Great René, I was really getting frustrated, a bit of coaching ... whenever ... you have my email now, I live near gearge clooney !!

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the extension with the builder? The easiest way is to create the fields (pickup-point, dropoff-point) in the builder, then create a `createAction` or `newAction` (not sure how it is called in the builder). It will create the template for the `createAction` where you can just copy/paste the `<f:form...`

There is a way to access directly POST/GET parameters (It is not recomended to use it directly when you can make it with the clean extbase way):

```
$myVar = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GP('myVar');
```

Comment: thx 4 the intrest: yes its done with the builder, but its kind of cross-over, I have this small form with two fields (pickup-point, dropoff-point) and the full form which starts with these two and has another 8 or 10 ...

Comment: I just need these two to be transprorted to the full form, there its going to be registered ...